# Terraform use count.index in nested dynamic block

Tags: terraform

I have the following code for a 'google_compute_url_map'

```
dynamic "path_matcher" {
  for_each = var.url_map_path_matcher
  content {
    name = path_matcher.key
    default_service = module.lb_http_serverless.backend_services[path_matcher.value.default_service].self_link
    dynamic "path_rule" {
      for_each = var.url_map_path_rules
      content {
        paths = path_rule.value.paths
        service = module.lb_http_serverless.backend_services[path_rule.value.service].self_link
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Due to the complexity of the variables I split the URL map and the path rules in two variables. How can I reference the index position of the first dynamic block variable in the for_each loop to be used across the two variables to make sure that the correct paths apply? Like in below example...

```
dynamic "path_matcher" {
  for_each = var.url_map_path_matcher
  content {
    name = path_matcher[count.index].key
    default_service = module.lb_http_serverless.backend_services[path_matcher[count.index].value.default_service].self_link
    dynamic "path_rule" {
      for_each = var.url_map_path_rules
      content {
        paths = path_rule[count.index].value.paths
        service = module.lb_http_serverless.backend_services[path_rule[count.index].value.service].self_link
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help or pointer in the right direction is greatly appreciated, been breaking my head over this the entire weekend.

Adding variable structure and example content as per request:

```
variable "url_map_path_matcher" {
  type = map(object({
    default_service = string
  }))
  description = "Variables to set the URL Map Path matcher"
}

variable "url_map_path_rules" {
  type = map(object({
    paths           = list(string)
    service         = string
  }))
  description = "Variables to set the URL Map Path rules"
}
```

Example content:

```
    "url_map_path_matcher": {
        "allpaths": {
            "default_service": "echo"
        }
    },
    "url_map_path_rules": {
        "path_rule_1": {
            "paths": [
                "/echo",
                "/echo/*"
            ],
            "service": "echo"
        },
        "path_rule_2": {
            "paths": [
                "/ping"
            ],
            "service": "ping"
        },
        "path_rule_3": {
            "paths": [
                "/my-new-svc"
            ],
            "service": "my-new-svc"
        }
    }
```

Expected to work with more complex setup like below variables:

```
    "url_map_path_matcher": {
        "allpaths": {
            "default_service": "echo"
        },
        "service1": {
            "default_service": "service1"
        },
    },
    "url_map_path_rules": {
      "allpaths": { 
        "path_rule_1": {
            "paths": [
                "/echo",
                "/echo/*"
            ],
            "service": "echo"
        },
        "path_rule_2": {
            "paths": [
                "/ping"
            ],
            "service": "ping"
        },
        "path_rule_3": {
            "paths": [
                "/my-new-svc"
            ],
            "service": "my-new-svc"
        },
      },
      "service1": {
        "path_rule_1": {
            "paths": [
                "/pingservice"
            ],
            "service": "pingservice"
        },
        "path_rule_2": {
            "paths": [
                "/service1"
            ],
            "service": "service1"
        },
      }
    }
```

Kind regards,

Eric V.

Comment: Could you show the variable input, variable type, and also the error message you are getting with using `count.index`?

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your reply. Here's how I tried to use it with the following error:
```
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on lb-http.tf line 49, in resource "google_compute_url_map" "lb01_url_map":
│   49:     count = length(var.url_map_path_matcher)
│ 
│ An argument named "count" is not expected here.
```
I added `count = length(var,url_map_path_matcher` to the dynamic "path_matcher" block.

Comment: Added variables and example content as requested.

Comment: To make sure I understand, you want to have 1 path_matcher with 3 path_rules inside of it correct? If you look at the [resource block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_url_map) and find `path_matcher` for `name = mysite` is that similar to what you want?

Comment: Will you plan on adding more `url_map_path_matcher` values in the future?

Comment: Well, initially, in the simplest form we use one path_matcher with 'x' path_rules, i.e. a one on one relation. But in a more complex situation (we'll have a lot of services), we might have multiple path_matchers with corresponding path_rules per path_matcher. That's why I'm trying to work out the 'index' position, to have the relationship between path_matcher and path_rules. I'll add an 'expected' more complicated variable content to the post.

Comment: Added more complex usage in variables, I know that I would have to modify the path_rules variable to be able to use that example but not sure into what.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, what if we tried something like this, could it work in your use case? Let's assume `allpaths` and `allpaths2` are the input for `path_matcher` `name` so in the case of his link there are two blocks of `path_matcher` created with each having their own defined `default_service`, `paths`, and `service`. https://www.codepile.net/pile/YpWLBBoJ

Comment: That would work for the basic one on one relation but what if there are multiple path rules and services? One default service is enough, but we would have multiple instances of path_rules and related service under a path_matcher name.

Comment: Thanks for the updated example. I was attempting to use the `lookup` function in Terraform but can't figure out how to access further nested attributes in `url_map_path_rules`. Have you posted this on the Terraform community forum yet?

Comment: No, not yet posted on the Terraform forum, I'll add it there too. Thank you @rk92 for time and patience spent already :-).

Answer (score 0):

Actually maybe this might be a start, test it out with your more advanced example and update with errors that you come across.

```
dynamic "path_matcher" {
  for_each = var.url_map_path_matcher
  content {
    name = path_matcher.key
    default_service = lookup(path_matcher.key, "default_service", null)
    dynamic "path_rule" {
      for_each = lookup(var.url_map_path_rules, path_matcher.key, null)
      content {
        paths = lookup(path_rule.value, "paths", null)
        service = lookup(path_rule.value, "service", null)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @tk92, throwing error as in https://www.codepile.net/pile/Vzo0ZDOd

Comment: Forgot to update the variable path_rules to be a map of maps. This is the updated error: https://www.codepile.net/pile/Vzo0ZDOd

Comment: @EricV. Try `default_service = lookup(path_matcher.value` instead of `.key`.

Comment: WOW, that worked @rk92! I'm not getting an error any more and `terraform plan` is not throwing an error anymore. We're validating the actual run to verify. I'll update you later today! Thanks a million again.

Comment: Great, sounds good. Definitely check to make sure the attributes are setup properly assuming we accessed each object in each map correctly. Especially for something like `path_rule1` in `allpaths` since there are two paths set there.